# How to implement the feature 'Move To Trash' to my CRUD app built with FastAPI?

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, psycopg2

I'm working on a Notes app project and I want to implement a new feature in my API that allows users to move a post to trash (if the user doesn't restore the post after a certain time it will be permanently deleted.),
Given two tables: Posts and Deleted, I want my endpoint **"./posts/totrash/{id}"** to insert a post in the deleted table and then delete this post from the table Posts:
Here is my code
(edit: the table Posts is "page")

```
@router.delete("/posts/totrash/{id}", status_code=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
def del_post(id: int, current_user=Depends(Oathou2.get_current_user)):
    user_id=current_user.id
    cur.execute("""select user_id from page where id = %s""", (str(id),))
    post_owner=cur.fetchone()
    if post_owner is None:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT, detail="the post with the id : {id} doesn't exist")
    if int(user_id) != int(post_owner["user_id"]):
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN, detail="you are not the owner of"
                                                                          "this  post")
    else:
        cur.execute("""select * from page where id=(%s)""", (str(id),))
        note = cur.fetchone()

        
        cur.execute("""insert into deleted(name, content, id, published , user_id , created_at)
         values(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) returning * """,
            (note["name"], note["content"], note["id"], note["published"], note["user_id"], note["created_at"])
                    )
        
        
# If a comment this following line, the insert will work
        cur.execute("""delete from page where id = %s""", (str(id),))
        conn.commit()
    return Response(status_code=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Now the selected post is deleted from the table Posts but when I check the table deleted I don't find the post which means It hasn't been inserted.

**EDIT**

```
#this is how I create the conn (connection)

class Database:

    def connection(self):
        while True:
            try:

                conn = psycopg2.connect(host=settings.host, database=settings.db_name, user=settings.db_user_name,
                                        password=settings.db_password, cursor_factory=RealDictCursor )

                print("connected")
                break
            except Exception as error:
                print("connection faild")
                print(error)
                time.sleep(2)
        return conn
database=Database()
```

In routes files:

```
from .dtbase import database

conn= database.connection()
cur = conn.cursor()
```

Comment: I am not seeing anywhere where `note` is defined so `note["name"]`, etc will error out. I suspect you meant to create `note` from the result of `cur.execute("""select * from page where id=(%s)""", (str(id),))`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Sorry I didn't pay attention, When I was writing my question i removed some print lines and I also removed an line where I defined "note"

Comment: done, "note" is a dict that contains the line that I want to insert

Comment: Then look at the Postgres log to see what is actually hitting the database.

Comment: Honestly, I've never tried to see Postgres Logs, I'll search in google.

Comment: Another to look at is that you don't have `deleted` table in more then one schema and you are running into a [search_path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) issue.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I have commented the line where I delete the Post and it worked i found the post in table deleted ! 
do you have any idea why this happened, how a query affects the previous query ?

Comment: 1) Update your question with your changes. 2) You will need to look at the Postgres logs.

Comment: How is the connection (`conn`) created? Could concurrent requests be using the same connection?

Comment: @snakecharmerb I made an edit. can't we use the same conn to execute more than one query ?

Comment: Using a single connection with concurrent requests is risky because all the requests will share the same transaction.  You can create a [pool](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/pool.html#psycopg2-pool-connections-pooling) instead.

Answer (score 0):

The approach that I used wasn't well structured.
what I did in the end is using only one table **Posts** and a column named **deleted** so if thr note is not deleted yet the value of **deleted** is false. When I delete the note I switch the value to true.